# Inserting LPAREN error in SML

Tags: sml, smlnj

I'm writing SML code to calculate the number of living people, dead people, and zombies over time, given specific formulas.
I've put my code into a ".sml" file and I open it in SMLNJ. The errors I get are as follows.

```
zombies.sml:36.3 Error: syntax error: inserting LPAREN
zombies.sml:43.1 Error: syntax error found at EOF
```

And here is my code.

```
val living = 500000.0;
val zombie = 0.0;
val dead = 1.0;

val counter = 0.0;

val d_ = 0.0001; (*chance of natural death*)
val z_ = 0.0001; (*chance of zombification after death*)
val b_ = 0.0095; (*chance of zombie attack*)
val a_ = 0.005; (*chance of a zombie dying?*)

val birth_rate = 1.0;

(*calculates amount of living*)
fun S(living:real, birth_rate:real, b_:real, zombie:real, d_:real) = birth_rate - b_*living*zombie - d_*living;

(*calculates amount of zombies*)
fun Z(zombie:real, b_:real, living:real, z_:real, dead:real, a_:real) = b_*living*zombie + z_*dead - a_*living*zombie;

(*calculates amount of dead*)
fun R(dead:real, d_:real, living:real, a_:real, zombie:real) = d_*living + a_*living*zombie - zombie*dead;

fun program (living:real, zombie:real, dead:real, birth_rate:real, b_:real, z_:real, d_:real, a_:real, counter:real) =
= if counter = 0 then 1
= else (S(living, birth_rate, b_, zombie, d_);
        Z(zombie, b_, living, z_, dead, a_);
        R(dead, d_, living, a_, zombie);
        counter = (counter + 1);
        program(living, zombie, dead, birth_rate, b_, z_, d_, a_, counter));

program(living, zombie, dead, birth_rate, b_, z_, d_, a_, counter);
```

Final, working edit.
Functional languages are weird.

```
fun add(x, y) = x + y;

(*calculates amount of living*)
fun S(living, birth_rate, b_, zombie, d_) =
round(real(birth_rate+living) - b_*real(living)*real(zombie) - d_*real(living));

(*calculates amount of zombies*)
fun Z(zombie, b_, living, z_, dead, a_) = 
round(b_*real(living)*real(zombie) + z_*real(dead) - a_*real(living)*real(zombie));

(*calculates amount of dead*)
fun R(dead, d_, living, a_, zombie) =
round(d_*real(living) + a_*real(living)*real(zombie) - real(zombie*dead));

fun main (living) =
let
    val living = ref living;
    val zombie = ref 1;
    val dead = ref 1;
    val birth_rate = 1;
    val d_ = 0.0001; (*chance of natural death*)
    val z_ = 0.0001; (*chance of zombification after death*)
    val b_ = 0.0095; (*chance of zombie attack*)
    val a_ = 0.005; (*chance of a zombie dying?*)
    val count = ref 1;
in
    while (!count < 10) do
    (
        living := S(!living, birth_rate, b_, !zombie, d_);
        print("Living count: " ^ Int.toString(!living) ^ "\n");
        zombie := Z(!zombie, b_, !living, z_, !dead, a_);
        print("Zombie count: " ^ Int.toString(!zombie) ^ "\n");
        dead := R(!dead, d_, !living, a_, !zombie);
        print("Dead count: " ^ Int.toString(!dead) ^ "\n");
        count := !count + 1;
        print(Int.toString(!count) ^ "\n")
    )
end;
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to write in some other language but with SML syntax. None of your functions have any side effect, so calling them in sequence doesn't accomplish anything. (And recursing with the same parameters will never terminate.) I would recommend that you forget what you think already know about how to write programs and learn some functional programming.

Comment: @molbdnilo Honestly, this is my first foray into functional programming, so there's a lot I don't get and I'm not enjoying it, so I would agree with your recommendation. XD

Answer (score 1):

Those `=` at the beginning of the line are clearly bogus:

```
fun program (…) =
= if counter = 0 then 1
= else (S(living, birth_rate, b_, zombie, d_);
```

Maybe the file got mangled in transmission?  (`=` is used as a line continuation character in MIME, but that would be located at the end of the line.)

Furthermore, integers and floating point numbers are distinct types in ML.  (This applies to literals as well.)  You need to make up your mind whether `counter` and `birth_rate` integers or reals.

The line

```
counter = (counter + 1);
```

does not have any effect.  Variables are immutable in SML.  You need to use a let binding instead, or just call `program` directly with the incremented counter value.

Comment: If I get rid of those, I get errors like: "operator and operand don't agree [equality type required], operator domain: ''Z * ''Z, operand: real * [int ty]".

Comment: @Paradox, I added a couple more comments.

Comment: `;` is an expression separator. It is not allowed directly before the `end`.

Answer (score 0):

To ask a question on StackOverflow that might be [useful for others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), refer to this section:

> **Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above:**
>
> - Questions *seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?")* must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

In your example, you've already determined that the problem is in the last part of your code, but since the last part depends on the first part, you can't simply post the last part, since otherwise the problem can't be reproduced. But syntax errors can.

1. Cutting down lines until you get to this point:

   ```
   fun program (living:real, zombie:real, dead:real, birth_rate:real, b_:real, z_:real, d_:real, a_:real, counter:real) =
   = if counter = 0 then 1
   = else raise Fail "Not relevant"
   ```

   will yield the same error.
2. Perhaps you are better off with a REPL that gives better error messages than SML/NJ.

   Compare for example the output of SML/NJ:

   ```
   typo.sml:24.3 Error: syntax error: inserting  LPAREN
   typo.sml:33.1 Error: syntax error found at EOF
   /usr/lib/smlnj/bin/sml: Fatal error -- Uncaught exception Compile with "syntax error" raised at ../compiler/Parse/main/smlfile.sml:15.24-15.46
   ```

   with that of [Moscow ML](http://mosml.org/):

   ```
   File "typo.sml", line 24, characters 2-4:
   ! = if counter = 0 then 1
   !   ^^
   ! Syntax error.
   ```